# How to determine whether object is composite (type) or not

Tags: go, struct, reflection, types

For example,  `x interface{}` is given. How it can be determined (maybe using reflection) if it is a composite type (struct or pointer to struct) or "simple" type like `string`, `int`, `float`, etc?

Comment: Do you consider a complex128 as simple or a composition of its real and imaginary part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use package [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/), obtain its type, and check its [kind](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind). If it's a pointer type, "navigate" to the pointed type:

```
func isStruct(i interface{}) bool {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(i)
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        t = t.Elem()
    }
    return t.Kind() == reflect.Struct
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(isStruct("text"))
fmt.Println(isStruct(1))
fmt.Println(isStruct(image.Point{}))
fmt.Println(isStruct(&image.Point{}))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UqrMF7fTr15)):

```
false
false
true
true
```

Comment: maybe you'd want:  `for t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        t = t.Elem()
    }` in case it's the rare case of pointer to a pointer